# Is it possible to represent a Class as a Field?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I need to retrieve annotation inside a class.
Imagine this:

```
@MyAnnotation(MyClass.class)
public Table myTable;
```

What I need to do is to initialize a variable inside class Table from a class inside the annotation.
The question is, how can I represent Table class as a field in order to retrieve a value from annotation like this:

```
Field tableField = ? // Here I should somehow cast 'this' to type Field
Class annotationValue = tableField.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class).value();
```

Is it possible to cast a Table class into a Field class somehow?

Comment: Annotations are for metadata. This clearly isn't metadata. Don't use annotations for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want access to the `myTable` field as a `Field` object, you would write:

```
Field tableField = Enclosing.class.getDeclaredField("myTable");
```

where `Enclosing` is the name of the class in which the `myTable` field is declared.

Answer (score 1):

> Field tableField = ? // Here I should somehow cast 'this' to type Field

An annotation doesn't depend on `"this"`, that is an instance of the class, but depends on the the class itself.

> The question is, how can I represent Table class as a field in order
>   to retrieve a value from annotation like this:

By reflection.

Suppose you have the class :

```
public class MyObject{
  @MyAnnotation(MyClass.class)
  public Table myTable;
}
```

You could retrieve the field in this way :

```
Field tableField = MyObject.class.getDeclaredField("myTable");
```

And then use the field to retrieve the value associated to the annotation:

```
Class<?> annotationValue = tableField.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class).value();
```

Comment: Okay, thank you!
But the problem is that it should not be dependent on a variable name or class in which the field is declared in my case.

Comment: In this case, I think that you should try to reformulate your requirement in editing the question. It is not very clear.